# Как с помощью js создать спектр аудио-трека?

Tags: javascript, аудио, web-audio

Столкнулся с проблемой поиска туториала по моей задаче - создать спектр аудио файла, чтобы в результате получилось что-то похожее на это изображение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где каждый пик - это средняя амплитуда громкости в конкретном участке аудио.

Во-первых, я не в точности не знаю, как это штука на самом деле называется (спектр?).
Во-вторых, когда я пытаюсь найти туториал, я нахожу только обработку звука в браузере в реальном времени. Аудио играет, звук анализируется, а dom-элементы на это как-то реагируют. Мне же нужно совсем другое. Мне нужна асинхронная функция, в которую я бы загрузил трек, она там своими алгоритмами как-то его обработала, а на выходе отдала бы массив с числами, где каждое число можно было бы использовать для построения штрихов для картинки. Эта процедура должна выполниться 1 раз при загрузке приложения.

Как это сделать?

Comment: canvas..........

Comment: audio api......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть абсолютно просто гайд на сайте mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API

Там как раз в результате генерируется итоговое изображение по аудио файлу.

Есть библиотеки, которые помогают это сделать (честно говоря, не пользовался ими). Например https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-audio-graph

Плюс прочие другие гайды на эту тему - https://css-tricks.com/making-an-audio-waveform-visualizer-with-vanilla-javascript/

Дальше выбрать наиболее подходящий/понятный и доработать под свои нужды.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Ссылаться на внешний материал конечно хорошо, но также нужно оставлять цитаты (и код если имеется) из ссылок, чтобы пользователи понимали что из ждёт из ссылки, а также это будет полезно если доступ к ресурсу был потерян. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Спасибо! Помогла статья с  https://css-tricks.com